Getting id_token with google cloud (replicate gcloud commands with curl)
I need to get id_token to access the third-party API. I have a credentials.json file with a private key, client_id, etc.
I would need to replicate gcloud commands:
gcloud --log-http auth activate-service-account --key-file=/tmp/creds
gcloud --log-http auth  print-identity-token --audiences=https://myurl.example.com

From the command line traces, the CLI makes several HTTP requests. The problem is that I can't find which payload is expected to be inside.
Note: There is no client library for it in my programming language, as far as I can see.

The gcloud HTTP logs are redacted by default for security reason. But you can deactivate the feature. Use this command
gcloud config set log_http_redact_token false

Now, you will see the body to provide to the Google Auth endpoint to get a token.
